# How to add Menu and Toolbar to a TopComponent Netbeans Platform

Tags: netbeans-platform

I'm quite new to Netbeans Platform RCP and i'm trying to find my way around a little problem. i know how to add menu and toolbar to Container of the TopComponent itself. What i want to know is how to add menu and toolbars to individual TopComponents.

Comment: What do you mean "add menu and toolbar to individual top components"?

Comment: Like in MulitView netbeans java documents where you have source / design and some other buttons right on top of the top component. The method I am currently trying to employ is to create a jMenuBar and JToolBar then i used a layout to place both at the top of the component. I was wondering if there are any inbuilt ways to do it, maybe with annotations or via the Layer file.